# Disassociate Foreign Key on django model for validation during editing

Tags: python, django

I have the following model:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    assigned_to= models.ForeignKey(user)
    (...)  # Some other fields
```

I create a Event instance

```
event = Event(assigned_to=someuser, **kwargs)
event.save()
```

If I have to use the Model validation features while editing the event,

```
event.assigned_to = None
```

for doing `event.full_clean()`,  django complains that it cannot set null a foreign key relation.

```
Cannot assign None: "Event.assigned_to" does not allow null values.
```

How should I get around this to get errors using the ValidationError raised during the `full_clean()` for a None specified to the foreignkey field.

Comment: assigned_to= models.ForeignKey(user, null=True) might help

Comment: that would not help if i dont want the database to be updated with events having no one assigned to them. @MadWombat

Comment: In that case, why do you need to assign None to your foreign key in the validation?

Comment: I was validating ajax submitted data for editing the object @MadWombat

Answer (score 0):

I managed to generate errors by using `null=True` on ForeignKey as @Mad Wombat suggested, and by overriding the clean method on the model to check if the assigned_to on the instance is not None

```
def clean(self):
    if self.assinged_to is None:
        raise ValidationError({'assigned_to': "Whatever error"})
```

As `full_clean()` calls the `clean()` method, it raised the validation error as needed.